# Eigen: function returning the same matrix passed as argument

Tags: c++, templates, eigen

I need to write a function taking an Eigen object as argument:

```
template <typename Derived> auto myFun(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& x)
```

I need to return the very same object that was passed as an argument. The reason I need that is that the function above is a special case of a function template that will perform a more general operation, but I believe that is not relevant to this question.

I would write

```
template <typename Derived> auto myFun(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& x){
    return x;
}
```

However if I run

```
Eigen::Array<double,5,1> sol;
myFun(sol);
```

I get the following error

*Calling a protected constructor of class 'Eigen::ArrayBase<Eigen::Array<double, 5, 1, 0>>'*

I do not understand what is happening, and how I should solve the problem.

Thanks!

Edit: I found a workaround that does not require changing the return type (since that will create problems and impact the rest of the code).

```
template <typename Derived> auto myFun(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& x){
    return x.matrix().array();
}
```

I suppose that the useless operations will be optimised away.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: however, why can the function not simply be `template <typename T> auto myFun(const T& t) { return t; }` ?

Comment: I cannot change the structure of the template, because it is a specialisation of a more general template. I anyway have not shown the rest of the code, I am building, since the error appears on the minimal code that I posted above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use a `base` class reference to create a copy of of a derived instance that is of type `base`. `Eigen::ArrayBase` does not seem to have a virtual `clone` so your options are basically...

return a reference (possibly `const`):

```
template <typename Derived> auto& myFun(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& x){
    return x;
}
```

or return the right type:

```
template <typename Derived> Derived myFun(const Eigen::ArrayBase<Derived>& x){
    return x;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/7nTMx1ncc)

Comment: Thanks! However that solution will impact the rest of the code. I would prefer to keep the return type. What do you think about the workaround I added to my questions?

Comment: @marco You can return `x.derived()` -- generally be careful with Eigen and `auto`.

Comment: Re: "`Eigen::ArrayBase` does not seem to have a virtual `clone`" -- this is because there is no virtual inheritance. Eigen (at least in the core part) only uses static polymorphism.